# React + Meteor. Generate async state depended on collection

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, reactjs

I have the React component in Meteor. It takes collection from getMeteorData(). Then it's getting the ids from this collection. With ids it have to get additional information by async function. This additional information must be rendered. But I have no idea of coding this.
I think code explains more. So, what I want:

```
Component = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

  getMeteorData(){
    var handle = Meteor.subscribe("Players");
    var player = Players.findOne(this.props.playerId);
    return {
      ready: handle.ready(),
      playerBasicInfo: player
    }
  },

  getAsyncStateDependedOnData(cb){
    if (!this.data.ready)
      cb({playerAdditionalInfo: null});
    else
      asyncGetPlayerAdditionalInfo(this.data.playerBasicInfo.id, function(result) {
        cb({playerAdditionalInfo: result});
      });
  },

  render(){
    if (!this.data.ready || !this.state.playerAdditionalInfo)
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

    return (
      <div>
        <b>First name:</b> {this.state.playerAdditionalInfo.fname}<br/>
        <b>Last name:</b> {this.state.playerAdditionalInfo.lname}<br/>
        <b>Age:</b> {this.state.playerAdditionalInfo.age}
      </div>
    );

  }
});
```

How to make **getAsyncStateDependedOnData** function?

Comment: What's wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: @Kyll I still have no implentatation but now) (sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I answer myself again. The solution is to use parent component, that will get meteor data and render our component as child with props included ready meteor data. The solution for question example is (arrow functions is used):

```
Component = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

  getMeteorData(){
    var handle = Meteor.subscribe("Players");
    var player = Players.findOne(this.props.playerId);
    return {
      ready: handle.ready(),
      playerBasicInfo: player
    }
  },

  render(){
    if (!this.data.ready)
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    return <_Component playerBasicInfo={this.data.playerBasicInfo}>;
  }
});

_Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      playerAdditionalInfo: null
    }
  },

  getPlayerAdditionalInfo(playerBasicInfo){
    this.setState({playerAdditionalInfo: null}, () => {
      asyncGetPlayerAdditionalInfo(playerBasicInfo.id, (result) => {
        this.setState({playerAdditionalInfo: result});
      });
    });
  },

  componentDidMount(){
      this.getPlayerAdditionalInfo(this.props.playerBasicInfo);
  },
  componentWillRecieveProps(newProps){
    this.getPlayerAdditionalInfo(newProps.playerBasicInfo);
  },

  render(){
    if (!this.state.playerAdditionalInfo)
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    return (
      <div>
        <b>First name:</b> {this.state.playerAdditionalInfo.fname}<br/>
        <b>Last name:</b> {this.state.playerAdditionalInfo.lname}<br/>
        <b>Age:</b> {this.state.playerAdditionalInfo.age}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I'm hoping that code havent any errors cause i didnt checked it

Comment: I like your answer. There is also disussion about this on: https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/issues/80